# Override Run button functionality | TFS 2013

Tags: tfs

I want to run a custom code on click of RUN button in TFS while selecting a test case/suite. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the **RUN** button at Test page is not support to override.

In TFS web page, the Run button for test suite/case is for manually test. But if you run automate tests with test suite/plan, please refer to this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff472576(v=vs.120)) for TFS 2013.

1. [Link your test case to test method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380741%28v=vs.120%29?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#Link%20test%20cases%20to%20test%20methods).
2. Create test controller and configure a Lab environment.
3. Create a XAML build definition to build your test project and publish your build artifacts to a path. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191495.aspx
4. In MTM, run that test suite or test plan.